# How to set the parameters of OpenCV3 calcHist() using vectors?

Tags: c++, opencv3.1

I am calculating a histogram from a greyscale image using the above code; it is working fine.

```
cv::Mat imgSrc = cv::imread("Image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::Mat histogram; //Array for the histogram
int channels[] = {0}; 
int binNumArray[] = {256}; 
float intensityRanges[] = { 0, 256 }; 
const float* ranges[] = { intensityRanges };
cv::calcHist( &imgSrc, 1, channels, cv::noArray(), histogram, 1,     binNumArray, ranges, true, false) ;
```

In the book of Kaehler & Bradski they refer to this as the "old-fashioned C-style arrays" and they say the new style would use STL vector templates, and the arrays of images from which to calculate the histogram are to be given using cv::InputArrayOfArrays. However, if I try to replace for example the channel array by:

std::vector channels {0};

Gives compilation error.So my questions are these: 
1. How can I define the arrays of the 'channels', 'binNumArray', 'intensityRanges' using vectors?
2. How can I define the array of input images using cv::InputArrayOfArrays?

Comment: I always found `calcHist` very wierd... you can compute simple histograms just like: `vector<int> histogram(256,0); for(int i=0; i<mat.rows*mat.cols; ++i) {histogram[mat(i)]++;}` It's also trivial to add quantization...

Comment: I know there are many ways of calculating a histogram without calcHist(), and even with calcHist with the 'old C-type arrays' it does work, I was just curious why I could't do it with vectors just like it says in the book. Thanks for the reply anyway (to Miki).

Comment: ok got it. Posted an answer with both methods (obviously the result is the same)

Answer (score 4):

This example show both the [*"old"* approach](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) and the [*"new"* approach](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga6ca1876785483836f72a77ced8ea759a), so you can appreciate the difference. It's based on the example found in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d).

The *"new"* approach is just a convenience wrapper that internally calls the *"old"* one.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Mat3b src = imread("path_to_image");
    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    Mat hist;
    Mat hist2;
    {
        // Quantize the hue to 30 levels
        // and the saturation to 32 levels
        int hbins = 30, sbins = 32;
        int histSize[] = { hbins, sbins };
        // hue varies from 0 to 179, see cvtColor
        float hranges[] = { 0, 180 };
        // saturation varies from 0 (black-gray-white) to
        // 255 (pure spectrum color)
        float sranges[] = { 0, 256 };
        const float* ranges[] = { hranges, sranges };

        // we compute the histogram from the 0-th and 1-st channels
        int channels[] = { 0, 1 };
        calcHist(&hsv, 1, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
            hist, 2, histSize, ranges,
            true, // the histogram is uniform
            false);
    }

    {
        // Quantize the hue to 30 levels
        // and the saturation to 32 levels
        vector<int> histSize = { 30, 32 };
        // hue varies from 0 to 179, see cvtColor
        // saturation varies from 0 (black-gray-white) to
        // 255 (pure spectrum color)
        vector<float> ranges = { 0, 180, 0, 256 };
        // we compute the histogram from the 0-th and 1-st channels
        vector<int> channels = { 0, 1 };

        vector<Mat> mats = { hsv };
        calcHist(mats, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
            hist2, histSize, ranges,
            /*true, // the histogram is uniform, this is ALWAYS true*/
            false);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks (Miki) for the example, I have figured what my problem was: if I use the vector formats the parameter list is different; I must not specify the number of images it should process (second parameter in the 'old' example.

Comment: Why does it say "do not use mask"? I used mask with non-empty values. It spits out an error `OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/username/opencv-3.4.4/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:904: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'calcHist'`